# How to get number of hours left from database time in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I Have following structure in my database :

```
id    |   date   |   time
(int)  (varchar)   (varchar)
```

is storing date & time like this :

```
date          time 
2020-07-04  06:15:00
```

Now i want to get those record whose current date & time is less than 2 hours, so i'm getting all records using normal select and

```
$current_time = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); 
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row->date.' '.$row->time);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%h hours');
```

but here what i'm getting is, if my database time has passed then also hours contains value, so if i want to get records which have 2 hours left when comparing the current time then after current datetime has passes then also i will get those rows but i don't want those rows whose time has passed.

Comment: can you please explain again what you what? i can't understand the last paragraph at all

Comment: @Berto99: I want to get all rows where difference in date time column and current time is less that 2 hours

Comment: do you have any models or i can give you a SQL query?

Comment: i'm using model $this->db->select('*')->from('tablename')->get()->result();

Comment: try adding `where datediff(hh, concat(date, ' ', time), getdate()) >= 2` to the query

Comment: @Berto99 : I have used this query but when i print using $this->db->last_query() it returs nothing removing this part query start working, where(datediff('hh', concat('date',' ','start_time'), getdate())>= 2)